# convert date stored in bigint field to a normal date format

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a method in a react.js file that saves date in a bigint field below

```
    getTodaysDate(){
        let formatTwoDigits = (digit) => ("0" + digit).slice(-2);
        var tempDate = new Date();
        var date = `${tempDate.getFullYear()}${formatTwoDigits(tempDate.getMonth()+1)}${formatTwoDigits(tempDate.getDate())}${formatTwoDigits(tempDate.getHours())}${formatTwoDigits(tempDate.getMinutes())}${formatTwoDigits(tempDate.getSeconds())}`;
        return date;
      }
```

This is what is saved in sql database

```
    20190313133112
```

I want to read this out and display in a meaningful format like below

```
    mm/dd/yyyy  [3/13/2019]
```

How can I convert this stored date to a normal date above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use replace.

```
^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2}).*
   |       |       |   |_____ Anything except new line
   |       |       |  
   |       |       |_________ Day   ( group 3 `$3`)
   |       |
   |       |_________________ Month ( group 2 `$2`)
   |        
   |_________________________ year  ( group 1 `$1`)
```

```js
let str = `20190313133112`

let op = str.replace(/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2}).*/,"$2/$3/$1")

console.log(op)
```

Comment: In my react code I am getting TypeError: value.replace is not a function

Comment: @user2320476 replace is a method on string. so must assures the `value` is in string form